# How do I get this modal window to open on load - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I downloaded a login modal from the following link. http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/login-box-modal-dialog-window-with-css-and-jquery/

I did some changes to the CSS, but that's about it.

Here is the jQuery code that launches the modal window when I click the button..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.loginbutton').click(function() {

    // Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
    $.fn.formLabels(); //Initialize form labels

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
    });
```

Basically, I need this modal to load on page load. I barely know jQuery, hence why I downloaded the plugin. I really need this to work.

I already tried to contact the guy who wrote this code, but he never replied back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a.loginbutton').click();
```

Just add that line, to execute the click event when the page loads.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is waiting for the user to click the login button before loading the modal. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//$('a.loginbutton').click(function() {

// Getting the variable's value from a link 
var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

//Fade in the Popup and add close button
$(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
$.fn.formLabels(); //Initialize form labels

//Set the center alignment padding + border
var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 

$(loginBox).css({ 
    'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
    'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
});

// Add the mask to body
$('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
$('#mask').fadeIn(300);

return false;
});
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
//});
});
```

I think I have commented out the .click() function.

Anything inside
    $(document).ready(function(){});
will be fired as soon as the page has finished loading.

anything inside $('a.loginbutton').click(function() {}); will only fire when the user clicks that button.